# Flot Graph not plotting data

Tags: javascript, flot

I a trying to plot some information using a flot graph but I can not get the values to appear on the graph.  This code was part of a demo file included in a template and so i have modified it to plot the data rather than using a randomise for the values, i am getting no errors but the chart isn't working and was hoping somebody could point me in the right direction.

My code is here:

```
 init: function()
    {
        // apply styling
        charts.utility.applyStyle(this);

        this.plot = $.plot(
            $("#chart_simple"),
            [{
                label: "Jobs", 
                data: this.data.d1,
                lines: {fillColor: "#dd3333"},
                points: {fillColor: "#dd3333"}
            }, 
            {   
                label: "Resumes", 
                data: this.data.d2,
                lines: {fillColor: "#282b30"},
                points: {fillColor: "#282b30"}
            }], this.options);
    }
},

// lines chart with fill & without points
chart_lines_fill_nopoints: 
{

    // chart data
    data: 
    {
        d1: [[1,100], [2,150], [3,100]],
        d2: [[1,100], [2,150], [3,100]]
    },

    // will hold the chart object
    plot: null,

    // chart options
    options: 
    {
        grid: {
            show: true,
            aboveData: true,
            color: "#3f3f3f",
            labelMargin: 5,
            axisMargin: 0, 
            borderWidth: 0,
            borderColor:null,
            minBorderMargin: 5 ,
            clickable: true, 
            hoverable: true,
            autoHighlight: true,
            mouseActiveRadius: 20,
            backgroundColor : { }
        },
        series: {
            grow: {active:false},
            lines: {
                show: true,
                fill: true,
                lineWidth: 2,
                steps: false
            },
            points: {show:false}
        },
        legend: { position: "nw" },
        yaxis: { min: 0 },
        xaxis: {ticks:11, tickDecimals: 0},
        colors: [],
        shadowSize:1,
        tooltip: true,
        tooltipOpts: {
            content: "%s : %y.0",
            shifts: {
                x: -30,
                y: -50
            },
            defaultTheme: false
        }
    },
```

Comment: A template from what?  Is there some JS framework this goes with?Can you post a link to the original code?

Comment: the javascript frame work is here goo.gl/vWaOxw and the original bit of code starts about line 753.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, digging a bit, I see you are using javascript from [here](http://www.mosaicpro.biz/).  Looking at a working example [here](http://cdn.mosaicpro.biz/quickadmin/php/assets/components/modules/admin/charts/flot/assets/custom/js/flotchart-line.init.js?v=v2.1.0), you've broken their code in the following ways:

1.)  You no longer seem to have a parent `charts` object, so

charts.utility.applyStyle(this);

isn't going to work.

2.) The `init` function is part of the `chart_lines_fill_nopoints` object, in your cut/paste code it isn't anymore.

3.) In your sample code you never actually call the `init` function to draw the plot.

4.) In the `options` `backgroundColor : { }` is invalid for flot (maybe this is part of the missing `charts.utility.applyStyle`).

Taking all this into account [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rQ5k6/) which makes this code work.

Generating flot plots with the above code feels unnecessarily convoluted.  Perhaps it makes sense when using these templates, but if you just using this as an example of how to call flot it's not very straightforward.

Also, please next time you post a question, include all relevant information (like where you found this code and how you changed it).  Taken out of context this code makes little sense.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated the detailed explanation really helps.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working

```
//Defining data for the chart

var data= 
{
    d1: [[1,100], [2,150], [3,100]],
    d2: [[1,100], [2,150], [3,100]]
};

//Defining options for the chart
var options=
{
    grid: {
        show: true,
        aboveData: true,
        color: "#3f3f3f",
        labelMargin: 5,
        axisMargin: 0, 
        borderWidth: 0,
        borderColor:null,
        minBorderMargin: 5 ,
        clickable: true, 
        hoverable: true,
        autoHighlight: true,
        mouseActiveRadius: 20,
        backgroundColor : { }
    },
    series: {
        grow: {active:false},
        lines: {
            show: true,
            fill: true,
            lineWidth: 2,
            steps: false
        },
        points: {show:false}
    },
    legend: { position: "nw" },
    yaxis: { min: 0 },
    xaxis: {ticks:11, tickDecimals: 0},
    colors: [],
    shadowSize:1,
    tooltip: true,
    tooltipOpts: {
        content: "%s : %y.0",
        shifts: {
            x: -30,
            y: -50
        },
        defaultTheme: false
    }};

// shorthand for document.ready
$(function(){

    this.plot = $.plot(
        $("#chart_simple"),
        [{
            label: "Jobs", 
            data: data.d1,
            lines: {fillColor: "#dd3333"},
            points: {fillColor: "#dd3333"}
        }, 
        {   
            label: "Resumes", 
            data: data.d2,
            lines: {fillColor: "#282b30"},
            points: {fillColor: "#282b30"}
        }], this.options);
});
```

Check out the working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8ppaW/) on jsfiddle.

Comment: You will see only one line on the graph because you have the same data for jobs and resumes. If you change the data for one then you can see the different lines on the graph.

Comment: Thanks i noticed in your example that it ignores the colours and fill points in the javascript?